# what is correct settings for 404 error on images and scripts?

Tags: error-handling, web-config, http-status-code-404

I have the following settings on web.config

```
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
        <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/404.aspx" responseMode="Redirect" />
    </httpErrors>
```

It seems good setting for missing webpages but for **images** and **scripts** if the src is missing, the 404.aspx is being set as the src of those elements. I think this is not a correct setting because server will fetch the 404.aspx in background and set it as the src of IMAGE or SCRIPT. Server resources, bandwidth, possible browser console warnings about missconfiguration of file types and search engine missleading etc. are the problems I am afraid about. Is there a recommendation about setting 404 error on specific type of elements? Any help is apreciated.